# »Charaktere« vs. »Figuren«

Tags: word-usage

Seit einigen Tagen höre ich in einer Fernsehwerbung für ein Produkt für Kinder einen Satz, in dem das Wort *»Charaktere«* verwendet wird (so, oder so ähnlich):

> Jetzt mit den **Charakteren** aus »(*Filmtitel*)«.

Ist es angebracht, hier von *Charakteren* zu sprechen? Wäre es nicht besser, stattdessen von Figuren zu reden?

> Jetzt mit den **Figuren** aus »(*Filmtitel*)«.

Comment: Direktübernahme aus dem Englischen. Hört sich angeblich viel besser an...

Comment: @Beta Dann hat das wohl Goethe schon gemeint: *im roman sollen vorzüglich gesinnungen und begebenheiten vorgestellt werden, im drama charactere und thaten.* (Das ist aus *Wilhelm Meisters Lehrjahren*)

Comment: @tofro Ich lese in Goethes Satz sehr viel mehr Betonung auf «Charakter», so wie in «Er ist schon ein Charakter für sich» oder, bei Schauspielern, «Er ist einer der großen Charakterdarsteller seiner Zeit.»

Comment: Ich finde, dass Zitat zeigt schon schön, wie die Begrifflichkeit entstanden ist - Nämlich gerade über den *Charakterdarsteller*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich denke, du hast recht. In gutem Deutsch würde man hier von "Figuren" sprechen, nicht von "Charakteren".

Kommentator Tofro führt zwar ein schönes Goethe-Zitat dazu an:

> im roman sollen vorzüglich gesinnungen und begebenheiten vorgestellt werden, im drama charactere und thaten

<sub>Quellennachweis siehe oben in Tofros Kommentar</sub>

aber als Argument, dass man im Zusammenhange deines Beispiels auch "Charaktere" sagen kann, taugt es in meinen Augen weniger.

Goethe hat hier - würde ich ihm einmal unterstellen - eben nicht "Figuren" (also Romanfiguren, Figuren einer Erzählung) gemeint sondern in der Tat "Charaktere" - nämlich Personen mit bestimmten (inneren) Persönlichkeitsmerkmalen und Verhaltenseigenthümlichkeiten. Bei den in der Frage angesprochenen "Charakteren aus [Filmtitel]" meinen weder die Autoren der Werbung noch das Werbepublikum solche inneren Eigenschaften. Es geht nur - oder doch überwiegend - um äußerliches Erscheinen, und dafür sagt man eben: Figuren. Eine gelbe Plüschente, einen Fledermausmenschen, ein grünes Monster, einen sprechenden Putzschwamm, was weiß ich.

So sprechen wir auch beim Schachspiel von "Figuren", nicht von "Charakteren". Es geht der Figur um die äußere Form, dem Charakter um die innere Gestalt.

Wir gehen ins Wachsfigurenkabinett. Über den Charakter der dort ausgestellten Persönlichkeiten diskutieren wir gesondert. Ein Wachscharakterkabinett müsste erst noch erfunden werden. (Es könnte nützlich sein für Charakterstudien.)

Frau Müller mag eine gute Figur haben aber einen schlechten Charakter. Und umgekehrt oder kreuzweis' (und Herr Müller natürlich auch). Doch sind es unterschiedliche Begriffe.

Comment: S. auch meine Antwort zu tofros Kommentar. Habe diese Antwort erst hinterher gesehen.