# Eine Figur von oder aus dem Film?

Tags: word-choice

Das ist eine Figur aus/von dem Film

Wie ist es richtig?
Eine sonstige Frage: Passt das Word "Figur" in dem Fall oder gibt es etwas passenderes?

Comment: _Charakter_ würde ebenfalls passen.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Siehe https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/39665/charaktere-vs-figuren

Answer (score 4):

> > Das ist eine Figur aus/von dem Film
>
> Wie ist es richtig?

Zunächst mal ist der Gebrauch von ***"von dem"*** nicht richtig, oder höchstens schlechtes Deutsch.
Die korrekte *Präposition* ist in diesem Fall *aus* oder *in*.

Es ist eine *Figur* **aus** dem Film, oder die **in** dem Film, oder **in** der Geschichte vorkommt.

---

> Passt das Word "Figur" in dem Fall oder gibt es etwas passenderes?

Das ist generell nicht falsch. Aber die folgenden Begriffe können,- je nach Emphase und Kontext -, ebenso gut verwendet werden:

- *(die/eine)* ***Person*** (die eine Rolle in der zu Grunde liegenden Geschichte spielt)
- *(der/ein)* ***Charakter*** (eine Person mit einer Rolle in der zu Grunde liegenden Geschichte, und die eine Stereotype oder ein bestimmtes Verhalten verkörpert)
- *(der/ein)* ***Protagonist/Held*** (eine Hauptperson)
- *(der/ein)* ***Antagonist/Bösewicht*** (der Gegenspieler der Hauptperson)
- *(der/ein)* ***Statist*** (eine Nebenrolle)

Je nach dem was betont werden soll, sind verschiedene (nicht unbedingt nativ deutsche) Begriffe verwendbar.

Comment: Wie wäre es damit, noch subtil den Genitiv einzuschmuggeln (eine Figur des Films)?

Comment: @user Nicht mehr heute, zu müde dafür. Und wenn dann würde ich es nicht mit einem simplen Genitiv lösen (hört sich Scheisse an), sondern eher _"Eine Figur (ein Charakter, die/der in dem Film vorkommt)"_. Feel free to edit! ;-)

Comment: @user Was mich vielmehr stört, ist dass ich so viele Fremdwörter für die Antwort verwendet habe.

Comment: Nein, rumeditieren mach ich nicht bei Usern, die täglich reinschauen, und selbst entscheiden können. Dafür schenke ich Dir zu Deinem Protagonisten einen Helden, zum Antagonisten vielleicht einen Bösewicht, aber natürlich kann es auch den Idioten des Films geben usw. "Der Film "Virginia", spielt der in Virginia? - Nein, das ist die Hauptfigur des Films." (Kansas ist nur eine Nebenfigur (Randfigur), die ich zum Statisten dazuschenke, ohne was gegen Statisten o. Protagonisten zu haben).

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde "aus" verwenden, um die Quelle anzugeben: eine Figur aus dem Roman / dem Film / dem Theaterstück / der Geschichte / der Oper.

Ich würde "von" verwenden, um den Autor / Urheber / "Schöpfer" anzugeben: eine Figur von Disney / eine Boygroup von der Musikindustrie.

Figur passt, oder Person (oder Hauptperson), oder etwas spezielleres: der Held aus Brechts Buch, eine Nebenfigur aus Wallace und Grommit.

Comment: _"um den Autor anzugeben"_ Huh?? Was hat der Autor damit zu tun?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Siehe Beisiel oben. Uhrheberschaft. Ich hab die Antwort ergänzt. Besser verständlich? Der Autor hat insofern was damit zu tun, dass die Frage nach "aus" oder "von" war, und ich erkläre, wie man "von" benutzen würde.